# An std::vector storing itself in a template class

Tags: c++, templates

I am examining how template class work, and I come with the following error:

```
template <class T>
class B
{
    public:
    std::vector<B<T> > queue;
    B();
    ~B();
};

int main()
{

    class B<int> tempQ();
    class B<int> temp2Q();
    class B<int> store();
    store.queue.push_back(tempQ);
    store.queue.push_back(temp2Q);
}
```

It gives me an compiling error:

```
main.cpp:52:8: error: request for member 'queue' in 'store', which is of non-class type 'B<int>()'
main.cpp:52:8: error: request for member 'queue' in 'store', which is of non-class type 'B<int>()'
```

Can someone give me some clue?

Also inside the template class B will it make a difference between

```
std::vector<B<T> > queue;
```

and

```
std::vector<B> queue;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two different problems. First, vexing parse:

```
class B<int> store();
```

declares a function called `store` taking no parameters and returning a `B<int>`, not a default-constructed variable. Just write `B<int> store;` or, in C++11, `B<int> store{};`. The `class` is also redundant and should be omitted.

Second,

```
std::vector<B<T> > queue;
```

instantiates a standard library container with an incomplete type (the type of a class isn't complete until you hit the closing `}` of its definition), which is undefined behavior. Depending on the implementation, you may be able to get away with it, but you really shouldn't do it. There are non-standard containers (such as [those in Boost's containers library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/container/main_features.html#container.main_features.containers_of_incomplete_types)) that are guaranteed to support incomplete types - use those.

> Also inside the template class B will it make a difference between
>
> ```
>     std::vector<B<T> > queue;
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
>     std::vector<B> queue;
> ```

No difference. Inside `B`'s definition, the `<T>` after `B` is implied when the context requires a type (as opposed to a template).

Answer (score 1):

In your code, "class B tempQ();" doesn't mean declaring variable
It's just declaring function.

here is solution..

```
template <class T>
class B
{
    public:
    std::vector<B<T>> queue;
    B() {};
    ~B() {};
};

int main()
{
    B<int> tempQ;
    B<int> temp2Q;
    B<int> store;
    store.queue.push_back(tempQ);
    store.queue.push_back(temp2Q);
}
```